# Inverse of a Poisson distribution function

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, poisson-distribution

I have two [i.i.d](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_and_identically_distributed_random_variables) random variables $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ following a continuous Poisson distribution function

$P(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda\cdot x}$.

I wish to obtain a distribution function of sum of two i.i.d random variables;

$Y = Y_{1}+Y_{2}$, where,

$Y_1 = \frac{1}{X_{1}} , Y_2 = \frac{1}{X_{2}}$.

To do this I would guess two steps-

1) Obtain the inverse Poisson distribution g(y) for $Y=\frac{1}{X}$

2) Obtain the distribution for sum of random variables $Y_{1}+Y_{2}$

I need help on how should I approach this problem?

Comment: What is the role of $P(x)=e^{-\lambda x}$ here? It is not a CDF and (if $\lambda>0$ and $\lambda\neq1$) not a PDF either.

Comment: It is an [exponential distribution function]. Actually it is $P(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda \cdot x}$. I don't know how to edit it in my question now.

[exponential distribution function]:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution

Comment: The CDF of exponential distribution is $1-e^{-\lambda x}$ and the PDF is $\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$. Both not the same as $P(x)$.

Comment: The mentioning of "Poisson distribution" in title and question can be confusing. You are dealing with the exponential distribution. I don't see a direct link with the Poisson distribution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:
If $X\sim Exp(\lambda)$, its cdf is $F_X(x)=1-e^{-\lambda x}$, $x\geq 0$.
Let us deduce the cdf of $1/X$:

$P(1/X\leq x)=P(X\geq 1/x)=1-P(X\leq 1/x)=1-(1-e^{-\lambda/x})=e^{-\lambda/x}$, $x>0$.
Its pdf is $g(x)=\displaystyle\frac{\lambda}{x^2}e^{-\lambda x}$, $x>0$.

If  $X_1, X_2$ are i.i.d. then $1/X_1, 1/X_2$  are also i.i.d., because:
$P(1/X_1\leq x_1, 1/X_2\leq x_2)=P(X_1\geq 1/x_1, X_2\geq 1/x_2)=P(X_1\geq 1/x_1)P(X_2\geq 1/x_2)=
P(1/X_1\leq x_1, 1/X_2\leq x_2)$.

Thus the sum $Y=Y_1+Y_2$ has as pdf the convolution of the pdf of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$, i.e.
denoting by $g_1, g_2$ the pdfs of $Y_1, Y_2$ we have $h(z)$ as pdf for $Y$, where
$h(z)=\int_\epsilon^\infty g_1(z-y)g_2(y)dy$, where $\epsilon$ is positive and close to zero.

Answer (score 1):

1) For positive $y$ we have:
 $$F_{Y}\left(y\right)=P\left(Y\leq y\right)=P\left(X\geq\frac{1}{y}\right)=e^{-\frac{\lambda}{y}}$$
Taking the derivative we find: $$f_{Y}\left(y\right)=\frac{e^{-\frac{\lambda}{y}}}{y^{2}}$$